# MPFR max integer value

Tags: c, mpfr

Do `mpfr_t` types have a limit on the largest integer value they can store or is the integer component effectively unlimited (only limited by memory limits on the target machine) like `mpz_t` types are?

If so is there an easy way to detect overflow whilst parsing a value?

Comment: MPFR is built upon GMP.  GMP has no real limits beyond available memory; it is reasonable to assume that MPFR is similar.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler There is a limit of 2^37 bits in GMP (for `mpz_t`), though it is quite large. I've mentioned it in my answer below, and also as [my answer to the specific question on the GMP limits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62530477/3782797).

Answer (score 0):

You can represent larger integers than what `mpz_t` can thanks to the exponent, but you may want to extend the exponent range with `mpfr_set_emax`, so that the maximum representable integer will be almost 2^(2^62−1) on a 64-bit platform. That said, you will not be able to represent *all* integers exactly since some integers (in particular the odd ones) would require too much precision. Concerning the limit on the precision, the theoretical limit in MPFR is `MPFR_PREC_MAX`, which is huge on 64-bit platforms. But in practice, you'll first hit either the limit from the amount of memory or the [limit of 2^37 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62530477/3782797) on the `mpz_t` size.